# Выборка наименьших ближайших дат из разных таблиц в одну

Tags: sql, sql-server

Нужно написать выборку данных по тарифам и нормам потребления на заданную дату, то есть доставать данные записанные в ближайшее меньшее от заданного значения время.

Написал процедуру выборки:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE GetServices
@Receiver varchar(15), @Date datetime
AS
BEGIN
SELECT
Receiver.Number AS ЛС,
Services.Name AS Услуга,
ServiceSubtypes.Name AS Подтип_услуги,
Specifications.Specific AS Норматив,
Tariff.Cost AS Тариф
FROM Receiver
JOIN Access ON Access.OWNER = Receiver.ID
JOIN Services ON Access.Code_Service = Services.Code AND Access.Rend = 1
JOIN ServiceSubtypes ON ServiceSubtypes.Code_Service = Services.Code AND Access.Code_Subtyped = ServiceSubtypes.ID AND Access.Rend = 1
JOIN Tariff ON Tariff.ID_Subtype = ServiceSubtypes.ID
JOIN Specifications ON  Specifications.ID_Subtype = ServiceSubtypes.ID
WHERE Receiver.Number = @Receiver AND Tariff.Date = (SELECT TOP 1 Date FROM Tariff WHERE date <= @Date ORDER BY Date DESC) AND Specifications.Date = (SELECT TOP 1 Date FROM Specifications WHERE Date <= @Date ORDER BY Date DESC)
END
```

И по-мимо того, что Тариф и Норматив ищут ближайшее наименьшее, они ещё и ищут ОБЩЕЕ. Т.е. если не находят ОДИНАКОВЫХ дат, в таблицу ничего не выводится.

Comment: Если что то не выводиться, значит в таблицах нет подходящих данных. Из вопроса не удается понять что есть и что требуется. Для ответов на подобные вопросы необходима структура таблиц, пример входных данных и результат, который необходимо получить на основе этих данных (в идеале  в виде примера на каком нибудь sqlfiddle.com)

Comment: А вообще подозреваю, что проблема вот в тех двух выборках top1, вы уверены что после всех join присутствует такая строка в которой обе даты были максимальны, причем максимальны глобально в своих таблицах, а не в зависимости от других условий ? Вот у вас там например reciver.number определенный, значит в основной выборке наверняка не все тарифы задействованы, а дату вы при этом из таблицы тарифов берете по всем существующим ...